# Emberjs - Model being reload

Tags: ember.js

My question might be a bit silly, but I would like to know what's happening when you reload the model from the controller.

For example I have an object with an array in it display in my website, and I'm updating this array by adding some new item in it.

Is the model display will be reloaded completely ? or it will just add the new data updated ?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are pushing/adding objects to the array, it just adds new elements to that section of the page, it doesn't re-render the entire section.  You can see this by modifying a portion of the DOM from the developer tools, and seeing that it retains those changes when you add those additional items.

Comment: And I assume that is the same for the controller variable too ? if I have `var array = [];` and if I push some item in it, it would work the same way as the model ?

Comment: Correct, (you'd want to use `pushObject`)